# What is the distribution of $\log(U_1)/(\log(U_1)+\log(U_2))$ if $U_i$ are iid uniform r.v.s?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Suppose $U_1$ and $U_2$ are independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. Prove that $\log(U_1)/(\log(U_1)+\log(U_2))$ is also a uniform random variable.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

The proof requires a preliminary lemma.

If $X_1,X_2$ are two iid r.v.s' exponentially distributed with parameter $\beta = 1$, then the distribution of $X_1/(X_1+X_2)$ is uniform on $(0,1)$. See [here](//math.stackexchange.com/questions/412615/x-y-are-independent-exponentially-distributed-then-what-is-the-distribution-of-x) for a proof.

Armed with this lemma, let $F(x)$ be the cdf of the r.v. $X_i = - \log U_i$. Then
$$F(x)= P( X_i \le x) = P (- \log U_i \le x) = P (U \le e^{-x}) = e^{-x}$$
for $x \le 0$ (and $G(y) = 0$ for $x < 0$). So $X_i$ is exponentially distributed with parameter $\beta=1$.

Therefore,
$$\frac{\log(U_1)}{\log(U_1)+\log(U_2)} \stackrel{d}{=} \frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2} \stackrel{d}{=} U$$
where $U$ is uniform on $(0,1)$.